# Why can't I change the color of one y-axis in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have a slight problem with my Matlab plot. It has two y-axes and I have to change the color of both of them, but only one of them works.

Here is my minimal reproducible example:

```
t=1:1:3;
a = [1 8 3];
b = [3 8 2];

figure
% green
yyaxis left
b1 = bar (t,b);
b1.FaceColor = "#008000";
b1.EdgeColor = "#008000";
b1x.YColor = "#008000";
hold on
grid on
ylabel('sth green here')
xlabel('sth black here')

% red
yyaxis right
ax.YColor = "#ff0000";
plot(t,a,'-x','Color', "#ff0000",'LineWidth',1)
hold on
grid on
ylabel('sth red here')
```

The green axis (the left one) is not green when I plot this, and I don't know why. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Where does `ax` come from?   Try using the return value from `yyaxis('right')`

Comment: First you do `b1x.YColor = ...`, what is `b1x`? And then you do `ax.YColor = ...`, what is `ax`? If we don't know what you are setting the color of, we're unlikely to figure out why your axes don't have the right color. Please include *complete* code, see [mre].

Comment: tbh I also don't know what ax is... I saw it somewhere on google (and it also wasn't defined in the code) but it works for the right axis but not for the left axis, so I tried out random stuff there... my code is really just what i posted here but with more values and other names of the axes